Application of $a_n$ = $S_n$ - $S_{n-1}$ for an arithmetic progression.
Consider the following question:
Let $V_r$ denote the sum of the first r terms of an Arithmetic Progression whose first term is r and common difference is (2r-1). Let $T_r$ = $V_{r+1}$ - $V_r$ -2. Then $T_r$ is always an:
(a) Odd Number
(b) Even Number
(c) Prime Number
(d) Composite Number (correct)
(This question appeared in JEE Advance 2007 Paper-1)
On most places that I looked, the following method has been used to find $T_r$ in terms of r:
Firstly, Expression for $V_r$ can be found using the formula for sum to "n" terms of an AP:
$V_r = \frac{(2r^3 - r^2 + r)}{2}
\\ \implies T_r = 3r^2 + 2r - 1 \ (as \ T_r = V_{r+1} - V_r -2) \\ \implies T_r = (r+1)(3r-1) \\ \implies \ T_r \text{ is composite.}$
But instead of finding $V_r$ to find $T_r$, I tried to use the fact that $S_n - S_{n-1} = a_n$ (where $a_n$ is the nth term of an AP). Using this, $T_r = r + r(2r-1) -2 \\ \implies T_r = 2(r^2 - 1)$
Since r must be a +ve integer, I am getting $T_r$ to be an even number. What is wrong in my method?

The problem states that $V_r$ is the sum of the first $r$ terms of an arithmetic sequence whose first term is $r$ and common difference is $2r-1$.  So $V_{\color{red}{r+1}}$ is the sum of the first $\color{red}{r+1}$ terms of an arithmetic sequence whose first term is $\color{red}{r+1}$ and common difference is $2(\color{red}{r+1}) - 1 = 2r+1$.  This is apparently the intent of the question:  Instead of thinking that $V_{r+1}$ is just $V_r + a_{n+1}$ (which is what you did), $V_{r+1}$ is not a sum of the same sequence that was summed to obtain $V_r$.
For instance, if I choose $r = 2$, then $d = 2r-1 = 3$ and $$V_2 = 2 + (2 + 3) = 7,$$
but if I choose $r = 3$, then $d = 2r-1 = 5$ and $$V_3 = 3 + (3 + 5) + (3 + 10) = 24.$$
Although there is just one more term as we expected, the common difference is not the same, and the starting term is not the same.  This is why your method does not work.  It is a very subtle trap.

Wow!!! What an amazing insight! Thanks a lot @heropup! :)
